# My Wifi has suddenly stopped working!! Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, dell, broadcom

I have Unubtu 16.04, 64bit installed on my Dell Inspiron 1525. I have to install "firmware-b43-installer" to get my WiFi working on Ubuntu. So after updating my computer, I did it and it was working perfectly for two days. All I remember is that I installed "zfsutils" and rebooted my computer and the WiFi stopped working. Please help!!

This is the current status:

lspci -v | grep -i network -A 6

0b:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11a/b/g (rev 01)

```
Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11a/b/g
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
Memory at fe7fc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: ndiswrapper
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kernel module `ndiswrapper` is wrong.

Remove it by

```
sudo modprobe -r ndiswrapper
sudo apt-get remove ndiswrapper
```

And start the proper module by

```
sudo modprobe b43
```

Comment: After a certain update the kernel module has been changed to "ssb" and now no matter what I do it is not going back to "b43" when I apply "sudo modprobe -r ssb" it says it is in use.

Comment: You can always ask a new question, then it will be possible to find out what the problem is.